# How to make very low range FM Transmitter?

Tags: radio, transmitter, frequency-modulation

I am experimenting with building an FM transmitter. I want to make it only have a range of a few meters so I can detect it on my radio at home at a distance of a few meters. The circuit diagram is below.

How do I make the transmitter have only a range of a few meters?

[image: schematic]

Image source: [Hackatronic - FM Transmitter Circuit Diagram and Working](https://www.hackatronic.com/fm-transmitter-circuit-diagram-and-working/)

Comment: Picowatt FM transmitters are commercially available for the very purpose your describe.

Comment: Hi Lexor, there's many questions in this one question post. Let's pick one, because that is how this site works. So, is the question A) "how is reception range related to transmit power?" ("wattage" isn't really a word, you mean power), or is it B) "how do I modify *this* transmitter circuit to have lower transmit power?" or is it C) "how does one go and build a low-power transmitter circuit for FM audio?"?, **So A, B or C?** In each case, you'll have to tell us exactly what you've researched so far.

Comment: B. I have reasearched how is power related to range but have not found anything. I have also researched how to make an fm transmitter have a lower range but the only answer I found on the internet was that it is related to battery voltage but nothing specific.  I already simulated the circuit in LT SPice so it works like i want it to, but I only want to modify it so that is has a range of a few meters. So B is the Question.

Comment: The FM transmitter I designed has a range of across the street to a cheap FM radio or a range of 2km to a high quality car radio. Yours might not have much range. The circuit you show will change its radio frequency as its battery voltage runs down and when something moves towards or away from its antenna. It will sound muffled on a good radio because C4 has way too much capacitance and the circuit is missing the pre-emphasis used by all FM radio stations. If your radio is played on its speaker then you will have audio feedback howling.

Comment: b) OK, what you found on the internet is just wrong. Range is a function of transmit power, path loss, and the sensitivity of the receiver. Transmit power in this circuit is *limited* by the battery voltage, but since this is a pretty terrible transmitter, anyways, primarily by the transmitter's design.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Antenna efficiency is also a factor.

Answer (score 2):

The radiated power needed to transmit a few meters at broadcast FM frequencies is in the nanowatt range. Unless you build the transmitter in a shielded box, it will likely radiate more than that without being attached to an antenna wire. If you want to reduce this, you may put it in a metal box, with only a short (few centimeters) wire emerging as an antenna.

Comment: Or possibly just put it into a metal box with your best, first, attempt at good shielding.  That rarely goes well when you actually _want_ to completely eliminate leakage, so a few meters of range wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: How could I for example make the transmitter emit around 500mW?

Comment: @LEXORAI 500 mW is impossible for this design. You'd have to make R6 smaller, but then you'd almost certainly toast Q2.

Comment: @LEXORAI 500 mW is *far* more power than you need. That will give you a range of km easily.

Comment: How do you know how much power a transmitter has, is there a way to calculate it? And how do you then get the the from that?